# PHP PDO login system failure

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am making a login system, but seems like any user with any password can get into my system.

I can make this system using mysqli, but I got problems with PDO. How do I solve it.

```
if(isset($_POST["login-submit"])){
    require "dbh.inc.php";
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $user_password = $_POST["password"];
    $user_password = password_hash($user_password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

    $sql = "SELECT count(id) FROM users WHERE username = :username AND user_password = :user_password"; 
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(["username" => $username, "user_password" => $user_password]);
    if($stmt->rowCount() == 1){
        session_start();
        $_SESSION["username"] =  $username;
        header("location:../index.php?login=success");
        exit();
    } else {
        header("location:../index.php?login=failed");
        exit();
    }
}
```

I have tested all other parts of code, seems they work nice when I register a new user, but if I use login form, therein anyone with any password can get into my system. It always shows login success even if I input a wrong user with wron password. 
I have also seen others questions on stack overflow similar to this but those codes are kinda complicated.

Comment: ..so what happens? Do you get the login=failed header?

Comment: I just updated the question

Comment: Also please research before asking any question on SO, see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)

Comment: I have seen that page, believe me when I go there and read the content it looks Chinese language. see this
password_hash ( string $password , int $algo [, array $options ] ) : string
I have never seen an array in a position like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are hashing the password again to check the validity of the password, instead you should use `password_verify` to check if the password is legit like.

```
if(isset($_POST["login-submit"])){
    require "dbh.inc.php";
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $user_password = $_POST["password"];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username"; 
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(["username" => $username]);
    $user = $stmt->fetch();
    $hash = $user['user_password'];
    if(password_verify($user_password,$hash)){
        session_start();
        $_SESSION["username"] =  $username;
        header("location:../index.php?login=success");
        exit();
    } else {
        header("location:../index.php?login=failed");
        exit();
    }
}
```

Assuming, you saved a user's password in the database with the `password_hash` function.
Also, after fetching with username, fetch the hash and then verify it with `password_verify()` function,

Answer (score 1):

(ASSUMING your database is one of the database that *does* return a row_count from a SELECT)

An aggregate sql will always return (at least) one row because the `COUNT` could be 0. Assuming id is unique primary key, no need for `COUNT`.

Comment: That is not the only problem in the question

Answer (score 0):

`rowCount()` is not meant to be used with SELECT statements:

> PDOStatement::rowCount() returns the number of rows affected by the last DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE statement executed by the corresponding PDOStatement object.
>
> If the last SQL statement executed by the associated PDOStatement was a SELECT statement, some databases may return the number of rows returned by that statement. However, this behaviour is not guaranteed for all databases and should not be relied on for portable applications.
>
> http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php

You need to retrieve and check actual result of your query execution, not merely check the fact that *something* happened when executing it.

Comment: I am new in PHP can you please write the actual code and edit the code above.